# mgcb-editor does not allow my project to start

Tags: c#, game-development, monogame

I am making my game on MonoGame, a technical demonstration, I have already fixed all the errors, Visual Studio does not issue any errors and warnings, but when launching it displays the mgcb startup error.
I apply it:

```
C:\Users\Andre\.nuget\packages\monogame.content.builder.task\3.8.1.303\build\MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task.targets(142,5): error MSB3073: выход из команды "dotnet mgcb /quiet /@:"C:\User
s\Andre\source\repos\Mission Phantasma\Content\Content.mgcb" /platform:Windows /outputDir:"C:/Users/Andre/source/repos/Mission Phantasma/Content/bin/Windows/Content" /intermediateDir:"C:
/Users/Andre/source/repos/Mission Phantasma/Content/obj/Windows/net6.0-windows/Content" /workingDir:"C:/Users/Andre/source/repos/Mission Phantasma/Content/"" с кодом 1. [C:\Users\Andre\s
ource\repos\Mission Phantasma\Mission Phantasma.csproj]
```

And game code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using MonoGame.Extended;
using MonoGame.Extended.Tiled;
using MonoGame.Extended.Tiled.Renderers;
using MonoGame.Extended.ViewportAdapters;

namespace Mission_Phantasma
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

        private Texture2D playerTexture;
        private Vector2 playerPosition;
        private Vector2 playerVelocity;
        private bool isJumping;
        private float jumpForce = -10f;
        private float gravity = 0.5f;

        private TiledMap tiledMap;
        private TiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
        private OrthographicCamera camera;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            playerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Player1");

            tiledMap = Content.Load<TiledMap>("map");

            var viewportAdapter = new BoxingViewportAdapter(Window, GraphicsDevice, _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
            camera = new OrthographicCamera(viewportAdapter);
            camera.LookAt(playerPosition);

            mapRenderer = new TiledMapRenderer(GraphicsDevice);
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

            float acceleration = 0.5f;
            float maxSpeed = 5f;

            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                playerVelocity.X -= acceleration;
            else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                playerVelocity.X += acceleration;

            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && !isJumping)
            {
                playerVelocity.Y = jumpForce;
                isJumping = true;
            }

            playerVelocity.X = MathHelper.Clamp(playerVelocity.X, -maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
            playerVelocity.Y += gravity;

            playerPosition += playerVelocity;

            camera.LookAt(playerPosition);

            mapRenderer.Update(gameTime);


            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            _spriteBatch.Begin(transformMatrix: camera.GetViewMatrix());

            mapRenderer.Draw();

            _spriteBatch.Draw(playerTexture, playerPosition, Color.White);

            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The game uses a map in the format .xml, it is possible that the project does not start because of it. I also tried to create a new project for Windows, copied the code, imported the assets, and mgcb gives the same error.

Comment: You need to provide waaaay more details. 1) what is your repo structure? are the files and folders in their expected locations? 2) what is your MSBuild configurations (.csproj, .sln, .projitems etc...)? have you changed anything from the Monogame template? 3) how are you adding your content to the game? are you using mgcb-editor or adding as content configuring build actions? 4) are you able to build the Content.mgcb file outside of VS? 5) can you show the content of you map XML? 6) Which processor are you using to load the xml Content? are you parsing into a c# class? Which one?